# How to create a ZIP package that can be deployed onto Azure

Tags: .net, azure, msbuild

I'm following [this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authoring-templates/) on how to create a JSON based template for deploying onto Azure.  It uses the MSDeploy extension so that the resource (a website in this case) can pull down the package from a URI:

```
"packageUri": "https://auxmktplceprod.blob.core.windows.net/packages/StarterSite-modified.zip",
```

If you download that file, you'll see a zip with various XML files (such as manifest, parameters, etc).

However, nowhere in this tutorial does it say how to actually *create* that ZIP file, preferably using MSBuild or something.  If I run:

> msbuild .\TestWeb.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true
>   /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true
>   /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true

It creates a ZIP file, but it doesn't appear to be *compatible* with Azure.  For example, it has no *Application Path* parameter which Azure appears to require.

What is the correct command line for creating a ZIP file compatible with the MSDeploy extension for Azure Resource Manager templates?  Basically, I want to know how Microsoft created the sample ZIP file above based on a SLN or CSPROJ.

**Exact Error from Logs:**

> > AppGallery Deploy Failed: 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentXmlException: The declared parameter 'Application Path' is not recognized.

Comment: Please share the exact error you get when you try to use the zip file.

Comment: @chief7 - Updated question with exact error.

Comment: @MikeChristensen did you find a resolution to this? Thanks.

Comment: @Shriroop - Nope, I quit that job so I no longer care :) I've been doing some Azure deployment scripts recently, but I've been using the REST API through Kudu.

Comment: Thanks @MikeChristensen . I have stumbled upon this "Application Path" not recognised issue and was hunting for some solution.

Comment: Hey @Shriroop, Did you find any solution to this error?

Answer (score 0):

Change `"Application Path"` parameter name to `"IIS Web Application Name"` in the template file.

I believe the template is attempting to set the IIS site name in the MSDeploy package via Parameterization.  WebDeploy creates this parameter by default.

Comment: "message": "AppGallery Deploy Failed: 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentXmlException: The declared parameter 'IIS Web Application Name' is not recognized." Doesn't work @chief7